# Setup for Playwright Test Auth State to Bypass Setup Dependency

Tags: testing, automated-tests, playwright, playwright-test, totp

I currently have to 2FA into an application to test it. I set up my playwright test project with the new standard of creating a `global-setup.ts` and a `setup` project that is marked as a dependency for my other projects in my `playwright.config.ts` file. The `global-setup.ts` handles my 2FA authentication, logging in, and generates a `storageState` into an `auth.json` file.

My issue is that when I run my tests `npx playwright test --headed --project=chromium`, it is going to trigger that `setup` dependency first and then execute my tests, but if the authentication is stored in the `auth.json` and the authenticated session last quite a while, is there a simple solution to have my project look to see if the authentication is still valid in `auth.json` and if not then it triggers the `setup` dependency to run before the rest of my tests.

it is probably super simple, I am just not seeing the approach. Any help is appreciated.

this question came up when I ran `npx playwright codegen --load-storage=auth.json` to record a test I was wanting to create. Is there a reason to authenticate every time I run a new test file if it is stored for lets say a few hours?

Comment: When you say "authentication is still valid", how exactly is that done? Is there some session cookies that expire?